# Bumblee settings

Tags: drivers, 13.10, lenovo, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have installed bumblebee on my lenovo W530 with Ubuntu 13.10. I have followed the guide given in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee and ensured that all settings are as in the wiki. When I run `optirun` I get the error:

```
"[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0."
```

However the graphics card K2000M is the pci bus :

```
"01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K2000M] (rev ff)" and the PCI setting is written into the xorg.conf.nvidia as "BusID          "PCI:01:00:0""
```

I have the packages `nvidia-settings-319`, `nvidia-settings`, `nvidia-319` and `nvida-331` installed and synaptic reports that they are version `331.20-0ubuntu~x`.

Any help in getting `optirun` working correctly is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] -> Changed Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP" line to Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none" and restart bumblebe from http://chrislaidler.blogspot.ru/2012/12/getting-nvidia-optimus-working-on-my.html

Jozamm